# How can we create a `TextIOWrapper` instance?

Tags: python-3.x, io

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#overview says, we can create a `TextIOBase` instance by

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

and a `BufferedIOBase` instance by

```
f = open("myfile.jpg", "rb")
```

How can we create a `TextIOWrapper` instance? For example, can it be done by using `open()`?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) (my emphasis):

> The type of file object returned by the open() function depends on the mode. When open() is used to open a file in a text mode ('w', 'r', 'wt', 'rt', etc.), it returns a subclass of io.TextIOBase (**specifically io.TextIOWrapper**). When used to open a file in a binary mode with buffering, the returned class is a subclass of io.BufferedIOBase.

Indeed,
`f = open("myfile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")` returns a `TextIOWrapper`:

```
In [18]: f = open("data", "r", encoding="utf-8")

In [19]: type(f)
Out[19]: _io.TextIOWrapper

In [20]: type(f).mro()
Out[20]: [_io.TextIOWrapper, _io._TextIOBase, _io._IOBase, object]
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you  a `TextIOBase` instance, which is not `TextIOWrapper` instance?

Comment: [`TextIOBase` is an ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy) (i.e., an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)). There is [no public constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase). `TextIOBase` is meant to be subclassed, not instantiated. The purpose of ABCs is [explained here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/).

Comment: `io.StringIO` is a subclass of `TextIOBase` which is not a `TextIOWrapper`.